# Assistance building a complex sql statement for vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms

I need to build a sql statement for loading a datagridview with entries for employees, but if the employee has been terminated obviously that entry shouldn't appear after the termination date. The ? will be replaced by the value of a DateTimePicker

I've tried a few variations of the statement, but i can't seem to wrap my head around it. I can say in regular english I don't want this employee to appear after the termination date, but I'm having trouble thinking the sql statment to acomplish it. For example:

The termination date should be < the DateTimePicker but this only shows the entries with termination date lower than the dtp.

I´m very new to codding in general. I'm using visual studio 2010 and the language is vb.net

1-

```
SELECT        Project, EmployeeID, HireDate, TerminationDate, Name, Middle, Last,
FROM            Employeesdb
WHERE        (Termination Date = False) AND (TerminationDate <= ?)
```

2-

```
SELECT        Project, EmployeeID, HireDate, TerminationDate, Name, Middle, Last,
FROM            Employeesdb
WHERE        TerminationDate <= ?
```

3-

```
SELECT        Project, EmployeeID, HireDate, TerminationDate, Name, Middle, Last,
FROM            Employeesdb
WHERE        TerminationDate <= ?
```

Comment: What kind of SQL are you using? TSQL? Oracle? MySql?

Comment: I'm not sure it's a regular sql statement for a bound datagridview that uses MS Access for database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about your database table structure, but something along these lines:

```
SELECT  Project, EmployeeID, HireDate, TerminationDate, Name, 
        Middle, Last,
FROM    Employeesdb
WHERE   (Termination Date IS NULL) OR (TerminationDate <= ?)
```

All employees who have not been terminated or 
those terminated prior to specified date

This assumes that terminationDate is a date field and can be left NULL if the employee is still employed...

Comment: If you have problems with the date test try using #...# as delimiters for the date string.